# Python: How to create a simple module and test it with virtualenv?

Tags: python, virtualenv, code-coverage, setuptools, nose

I need your help.

I am trying to create a simple but complete Hello World module with setuptools and I would like to check it with virtualenv, nose and coverage but when I run this command `nosetests --with-coverage --with-xunit --cover-package=helloworld --cover-erase` inside a `virtualenv`, I have this output:

```
Coverage.py warning: Module helloworld was never imported.
Coverage.py warning: No data was collected.
Name    Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
-------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s
```

I don't know yet if it is better to embed my tests in a submodule or in a separate folder so, my idea was to create a simple module with test that are in a submodule and other test in another folder.
Anyway, here is my project structure:

```
helloworld/
    python/
        helloworld/
            __init__.py
                #!/usr/bin/python
                # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
                from functions import hello_world
            __main__.py
                #!/usr/bin/python
                # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
                from functions import hello_world
                hello_world()
            functions.py
                #!/usr/bin/python
                # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
                def hello_world():
                    print("Hello World!")
            test\
                __init__.py
                    #!/usr/bin/python
                    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
                helloworld.py
                    #!/usr/bin/python
                    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
                    import unittest
                    class HelloWorldInsideTester(unittest.TestCase):
                        def test_true(self):
                        self.assertTrue(True)
        test/
            helloworld.py
                #!/usr/bin/python
                # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
                import unittest
                class HelloWorldTester(unittest.TestCase):
                    def test_true(self):
                    self.assertTrue(True)
    setup.py
        #!/usr/bin/python
        # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
        from setuptools import setup
        setup(
            name='helloworld',
            version='0.1',
            license='GPL',
            description="Hello World testing setuptools",
            long_description="README.txt",
            packages=['helloworld']
        )
build.bat
    @echo off
    set BUILD_DIR=tmp\
    set WORKING_DIR=tmp\working_copy\
    set PYENV_DIR=tmp\pyenv\
    if exist "%BUILD_DIR%" ( rmdir /s /q "%BUILD_DIR%" )
    virtualenv %PYENV_DIR% -p C:\Python27\python.exe
    call %PYENV_DIR%Scripts\activate
    pip install -e "python"
    pip install coverage
    pip install nose
    nosetests --with-coverage --with-xunit --cover-package=helloworld --cover-erase
    nosetests --with-coverage --with-xunit --cover-package=nose --cover-erase
    nosetests --with-coverage --with-xunit --cover-package=coverage --cover-erase
    deactivate
```

Everything is working. `nosetests` works for `nose` and `coverage` but not for my `helloworld`.
I don't know what's wrong.
Can you help me please ?

Comment: That seems like a complex way of organising it. Have a look at e.g. http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/08/16/open-sourcing-a-python-project-the-right-way/

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think there is nothing complicated. I have a root folder for my project and a sub folder for python source code. Since my project will include other programing language, I need this. Inside the python folder, it is just traditional layout (I think). The only particularity are the two test folders but that's only because I want to be able to use both layout. If you can make it work with only one test folder (you choose ;), that's fine for a start.

Comment: what path are you on when you run `nosetests`? since there is no package (dir containing an `__init__.py`) at the top level nose probably needs a hint about where to look http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/finding_tests.html

Comment: what does `which nose` prints? did you install it in virtulaenv like `pip install -I nose` ?

Comment: @Anentropic The `build.bat` is run from where it is located, so, the path is at the root of the project.
@Vor On Windows, I can't get the info but I am 100% sure it is installed in virtualenv.

Comment: The thing that I don't understand is that the `nosetests` command do work for `nose`or `coverage` but not for my `helloworld` so, there must be something that I am missing. Maybe I just need the good documentation but I can't find it...

Comment: if you mean that tests for the `nose` and `coverage` installed packages are run, it's because these are on your `PYTHONPATH` by virtue of being installed in the virtualenv... whereas your helloworld app is sitting hidden in a subdirectory but not 'installed'... you either need to add `helloworld/python` to your path or tell nose exactly where to look with a command line option

Comment: @Anentropic So, you're telling me that this command `pip install -e "python"` does not install my helloworld? But the output say: `Installing collected packages: helloworld Running setup.py develop for helloworld Creating c:\users\ncenerar\git\helloworld\tmp\pyenv\lib\site-packages\helloworld.egg-link (link to .) Adding helloworld 0.1 to easy-install.pth file Installed c:\users\ncenerar\git\helloworld\python Successfully installed helloworld`

Comment: I added `python -m helloworld` in my `build.bat` and I get "Hello World!" so, my package has been installed and is callable... I really don't get it...

Comment: oh, hmm didn't see the source of your build.bat ...in that case I think you may need to change `test/helloworld.py` so the filename starts with "test" http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/writing_tests.html?highlight=testmatch#writing-tests